# Saving resources to different tables in Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I wonder if it would be possible to save information from one resource field to two different tables in MySQL? For example, if I am creating a new post in Laravel Nova and my code is:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        Text::make('text one', 'text_one')->required(),
        Text::make('text two', 'text_two')->required(),
    ];
}
```

Would it be possible to save text_one to MySQL table1 and text_two to MySQL table2? I want both of these fields to be in the same form, and they both must create a new row on the database tables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, but you have to use '[Resource Hooks](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/#resource-events)'. Take a look and for '[Resource Events](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/#resource-hooks)' (Laravel model observer)